# If a body experiences air resistance while falling can we say that it is in free fall?

Tags: free-fall

We know that free fall is when an object is acted upon by only gravity. But in practical cases, air resistance acts on every object that is falling from a height. So can we call their motion as free fall motion even when they are acted upon by air resistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term free fall means that the only force that is acting on the object is gravity: it is moving down solely because of its weight.

Such is only achievable in an ideal situation, with no air resistance or other forces of sorts acting on the body.  It is also achievable in vacuum.

Comment: So a body experiencing air resistance is not in free fall, right?

Comment: Yes, definitely not.